# Sine wave in my residuals graph

Tags: experimental-physics, experimental-technique, data-analysis

We had a physics experiment where we should have had a linear relation between 2 measured values, we got a pretty good fir however our residuals plot has a kind of a sine wave behaviour. 
We were told that a sine wave in the residuals graph is a "big no no" even if the residuals fall into our first uncertainty assumptions.
How should I estimate my relation bettet ? What should be taken into account?
Sorry for not givin specific examples it just happened to me many many times and I would like to get a general answer/ idea about this.

Thanks

Comment: With further information about the experiment, the fit method, the measured values, this is unanswerable. Usually, patterns in the residuals just mean that there is some systematic error in the setup that you have not taken into account, it doesn't get more specific than that.

Comment: The residuals should be random noise, and anything else usually means there's a systematic error you've missed. Not disastrous, but something you should look into. There's not much more we can say based on the limited information you've posted.